# python-six misconfiguration?

Tags: python-2.7, six

This on CentOS 7

```
[root@dhcppc7 ~]# pip freeze | grep six
six==1.10.0
[root@dhcppc7 ~]# python -c 'import six; print(six.__version__)'
1.2.0
```

How can I force my python script to use six 1.10.0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a work around to this problem is to manually install six on your system:

```
# wget https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/s/six/six-1.10.0.tar.gz#md5=34eed507548117b2ab523ab14b2f8b55
# tar -zxvf six-1.10.0.tar.gz
# python ./six-1.10.0/setup.py install

# python -c 'import six; print(six.__version__)'
1.10.0
```